# Navigation ideas for multiple categories - iOS

Tags: navigation, ios

I am building a news app for iPhones.

The app has five main sections which are news, videos, articles ( different from new ), settings and favorites. All these sections are tabbed at the bottom using Tab Bar Controller. Example as below:

[image]

But for news and videos, there are categories which users can select such as "Latest", "Top News" etc. How do I view these categories while maintaining a clean look? Android has a slider tab element which works, but on iOS, I can't seem to find these second tier navigation options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bottom Tabs to show your main functionalities.
In your example News on Tab and Create Segmented Tabs inside a tab and add latest there.
Check image

[image]

Comment: The categories is a long list. It has at least six items. Won't it look a little crowded?

Answer (score 1):

According to [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/) (emphasis mine):

> Each additional tab reduces the tappable area for selecting a tab and increases the complexity of your app, making it harder to locate information. Although a More tab can display extra tabs, this requires additional taps and is a poor use of space. Include essential tabs only, and use the minimum tabs necessary for your information hierarchy. Too few tabs can be a problem too, as it can make your interface feel disconnected. **In general, use between three and five tabs on iPhone**. A few more are acceptable on iPad.

---

In Material design the [Tab bar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html?authuser=3&hl=it#tabs-usage) can be scrollable:

[image]

---

However in a [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage), like the one you show in the image, Material design doesn't recommend making it scrollable:

> **Don't**.
>
> Avoid scrollable content in the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my problem remains. I still have a vague idea on how to display the categories. There are about at least 6 categories each, which means I can't use the tabs.